# Is it possible to split JavaScript across multiple files and access functions from each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I would like to do is have a JavaScript file which would contain jQuery functions that are used across multiple sites (all hosted on the same CMS - eTouches, so there is no cross domain scripting issue) and then have a site specific JavaScript file for each site which utilised the functions, making it easy to change the central function file as needed.

I am getting errors when trying to do this though, with functions not being defined when the second script it trying to execute things. Is this a possible and have I missed something basic or is it something that is not possible.

I don't think it is possible to include files as you do in PHP etc, but if I call the functions file before the site specific one I thought this should work?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Code from function document

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$('<a href="#" class="mobile-menu-toggle-link">&#9776; Menu</a>').insertBefore($('.ehtm'));

if ($('#right_sidebar_section').length) {
} else {
    $('#main_section').css('width','100%')
    $('#main_section').css('marginLeft','0')
}

var mobileMenu = function (menuParent, prevSibling, menuIdentifier) {
    if ($('#mobileMenu').length == 0) {
        var $select = $('<div>', {
            'class': 'mobile-menu',
            'id': menuIdentifier
        }).insertBefore(prevSibling);
        $('.ehtm > ul').prependTo($('#mobileMenu'));
    }

    if ($('.expandContract').length==0) {
        $('.mobile-menu > ul > li > a').each(function(){
            $(this).css("width", "120px");
            $('<a href="#" class="expandContract">+<span></span></a>').insertBefore($(this));
        })
    }

    $('.expandContract').click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $(this).text($(this).text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');
        $(this).parent().find("ul").slideToggle();
        evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
    })
};

var menuReset = function () {
    $('.mobile-menu > ul').prependTo($('.ehtm'));
    $('#mobileMenu').remove();
    if (parseInt($('#outer_table').css('margin-left')) > 0) {
        $('#outer_table').animate({
            marginLeft: parseInt($('#outer_table').css('marginLeft'), 10) == 0 ? 200 : 0
        });
    }

    $('a.expandContract').each(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    })

    $('.ehtm > ul > li > a').each(function(){
        $(this).css('width','auto');
    })
}

$('.mobile-menu-toggle-link').click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    $('#outer_table').animate({
        marginLeft: parseInt($('#outer_table').css('marginLeft'), 10) == 0 ? 200 : 0
    });

    $('.header').animate({
        marginLeft: parseInt($('#outer_table').css('marginLeft'), 10) == 0 ? 200 : 0
    });

    $('.mobile-menu').animate({
        marginLeft: parseInt($('#outer_table').css('marginLeft'), 10) == 0 ? 0 : -200
    });

    var wHeight = $(window).innerHeight();

    var divHeight = $('#mobileMenu').height();

    if (wHeight > divHeight) {
        $('.mobile-menu').css("height", wHeight);
    } else {
        $('.mobile-menu').css("height", divHeight);
    }

})

var compareWidth = $('.header').width();

/* Add class to the first table row, to allow header styling */

var headRow = $("table#outer_table").find("tr:first");
$(headRow).addClass("headerBGColor");

});
```

Code from site specific document

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

var compareWidth = $('.header').width();

var setUpPage = function () {
    if (compareWidth < 768) {
        mobileMenu('.ehtm li', '.header', 'mobileMenu');
    }

    if (compareWidth >= 768) {
        menuReset();
    }

    /* Header image swap */

    if (compareWidth>=1024) {
        $("#headerImage").attr("src","https://www.eiseverywhere.com/image.php?acc=xxx&id=xxxxxx");
    } else if ((compareWidth>=768) && (compareWidth<1024)) {
        $("#headerImage").attr("src","https://www.eiseverywhere.com/image.php?acc=xxx&id=xxxxxx");
    } else {
        $("#headerImage").attr("src","https://www.eiseverywhere.com/image.php?acc=xxx&id=xxxxxx");
    }

    /* Carousel */

    if ($('.owl-carousel').length > 0) {
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            items:1,
            loop:true,
            margin:10,
            autoplay:true,
            autoplayTimeout:3000,
            dots:true
        });
    }
}

var breakPointCheck = function () {
    var currentWidth = $('.header').width();
    if (currentWidth != compareWidth) {
        compareWidth = currentWidth;
        setUpPage();
    }
}

setUpPage();
//    fixElement('.tabmenu')
$(window).resize(function () {
    breakPointCheck();
});
});
```

Comment: Perhaps something like http://capmousse.github.io/include.js/?

Answer (score 4):

They are all declared in DOM ready functions which give them a `local` scope. The functions cannot then be seen outside of that function and each DOM ready function is separate to the others.

You need to declare them as global functions instead (using global vars):

e.g.

```
// Global scope
var mobileMenu;

$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
     // Aside local function to global var
     mobileMenu = function(...
```

The alternative is to declare the functions outside of the DOM ready handlers and make sure they are only called from code inside of DOM ready handlers. Most of the functions shown do not need to be inside DOM ready handlers as they are just declarations and are not run at that point:

e.g.

```
$.noConflict();

//Declare global functions
var mobileMenu = function (menuParent, prevSibling, menuIdentifier) {
    if ($('#mobileMenu').length == 0) {
        var $select = $('<div>', {
            'class': 'mobile-menu',
            ...snip...
 });

 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      // Use global functions
      mobileMenu(...);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use jQuery.getScript()

In your shared function script, remove the `jQuery(document).ready(function () {...})` wrapper.

In your site-specific document, use `$.getScript()` to load the shared file and place your site-specific functions in a callback that runs after the shared script loads successfully:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript('/url/to/functionScript.js', function () {
        // Site specific functions
    });
});
```